# completely media-less kexec install of a rhel-based distro?

Tags: redhat, kickstart, anaconda

I'd like to be able to install a small redhat server from kexec without media being present on the system during the installation (no hdd, removable media, or network).
This seems feasible because I can generate and kexec boot an initramfs of the relevant size without trouble and kexec loads the whole initramfs into memory at load-time, allowing the initramfs programs to overwrite the storage that originally hosted the initramfs.
I've tried adding the Packages and repodata directory trees to an initrd, and tried getting kickstart to recognize them with inst.repo=file:///myrepo, but upon further investigation, it appears the repo is expected to be mounted by some python scripting into /run/install/repo after a root pivot from the original initrd to an install.img.

I'm trying to figure out how to embed this repo in the initrd (or some nested static filesystem image within it) in order to get it to fully install from kexec without any external resources (ie, hdd or cd/removable media because the installation will write over all storage in the system).

The only thing I can think of, is maybe embed the repo directories in the rootfs.img, then have kickstart's %pre run losetup on the image and loopback mount it into /run/install/repo.

I can't tell whether this has been done before, as I've searched quite a bit with no luck.  I've also looked for anaconda/kickstart mailing lists for assistance without finding anything there either.